# Did the Romans use any other materials to reinforce their concrete?

Tags: ancient-rome, construction

I have been reading about Roman concrete (300BC-300AD) and how it has greater strength than current concrete mixtures.  So far, my research has shown that they did not use re-bar in their structures. But did the Romans use anything external (like fiber, wood, etc) to improve their concrete's tensile strength?

For reference this was the source I was reading:

[The Mechanics of Imperial Roman Concrete and the
Structural Design of Vaulted Monuments](https://urresearch.rochester.edu/institutionalPublicationPublicView.action?institutionalItemVersionId=14360)

Comment: So you looked over [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_concrete), which discusses volcanic ash?

Comment: Are you just interested in the tensile strength of Roman concrete, or other aspects as well?

Comment: I have read all about their various mixtures and the components involved.  I am more interested in if they used anything external to reinforce their concrete.  @sempaiscuba I am mainly interested in how they got enough tensile strength to span large gaps, but really if you have any interesting information on Roman concrete I would be happy to read about it.

Comment: Well, there is [Vitruvius](http://www.vitruvius.be/boek2h6.htm), obviously, and I did recently read [this article](https://phys.org/news/2017-07-ancient-concrete-romans.html) from phys.org, but it may not have anything you don't already know.

Comment: Typically the Romans used *arches* to span large gaps - putting everything into compression instead of tension. Just look at their aqueducts and bridges.

Comment: What about the spans that did not have arches in them.  I have seen some straight spans, I am trying to find the pictures right now, if i can find them I will post them in the original post.

Comment: Your source is discussing *vaulted* constructions as well, though I admit I have not gone through the entire 456 page thesis, yet.

Comment: The only addition I'm 100% sure of were small terracotta jars added to the mix for the Pantheon's dome, used to reduce the overall weight.

Comment: The thesis listed in the question discusses a variety of different *caementa* (what we would call aggregate) or materials used in the concrete mixtures to variously increase or decrease the concretes density. Travertine and brick pieces in lower regions, to pumice used in roof or ceiling arch structures. Quite interesting.

Comment: @justcal yes, it was rather technical in places, but very fascinating stuff indeed.  you really have to give the Roman builders credit for some of the stuff they came up with. I have always been impressed with their construction prowess.

Comment: @ed.hank Yes, they did some fascinating stuff. Did you ever find a reference for a straight span, without arch support? I like the question, but just can't seem to see an answer. The mixtures and the engineering  really were the difference.